# Read from string-array sharedpreferences

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to read sharedpreferences default values from string-array that I have created in XML file.

Sharedpreferences GET java code:

```
private String getItemQuantity(String key){
    SharedPreferences itemQuantitySP = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("bifrostPrefs", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Resources res = getResources();
    String[] spBifrost = res.getStringArray(R.array.spBifrost);
    return itemQuantitySP.getString(key, spBifrost.toString());
}
```

String-array XML:

```
<string-array name="spBifrost">
    <item>Elaborate Totem (250)</item>
    <item>Pile of Crystalline Dust (250)</item>
    <item>Powerful Venom Sac (250)</item>
    <item>Vial of Powerful Blood (250)</item>
    <item>Ancient Bone (250)</item>
    <item>Armored Scale (250)</item>
    <item>Vicious Claw (250)</item>
    <item>Vicious Fang (250)</item>
    <item>Glob of Ectoplasm (77)</item>
    <item>Glob of Ectoplasm (77)</item>
    <item>Mystic Coin (77)</item>
    <item>Obsidian Shard (77)</item>
    <item>Philosophers Stone (462)</item>
    <item>Badge of Honor (500)</item>
    <item>Obsidian Shard (250)</item>
    <item>Shard of Zhaitan (500)</item>
    <item>Opal Orb (100)</item>
    <item>Pile of Crystalline Dust (250)</item>
    <item>Unidentified Dye (250)</item>
    <item>Pile of Crystalline Dust (250)</item>
    <item>Pile of Incandescent Dust (250)</item>
    <item>Pile of Luminous Dust (250)</item>
    <item>Pile of Radiant Dust (250)</item>
    <item>Icy Runestone (100)</item>
</string-array>
```

Now, whenever I use sharedpreferences, it automatically reads default value as [Ljava.lang.String;@435ec530 and I have no idea where it gets that from and how to fix it. I have 24 checkboxes and I want it to use first item for checkbox1, second item for checkbox2, etc.

Calling getItemQuantity:

```
cb4.setText(getItemQuantity("cb4quantity"));
String[] spBifrost = getItemQuantity("cb4quantity").split(";");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to create String by using separator from current String Array before passing it to as default value to `SharedPreferences.getString` method as:

```
String[] spBifrost = res.getStringArray(R.array.spBifrost);
StringBuilder stringbuffer = new StringBuilder();
for(String item : str_arr) {
  stringbuffer.append(item).append(";");
}
return itemQuantitySP.getString(key, stringbuffer.toString());
```

now after getting String from `SharedPreferences` you will need to get String Array from it using `String.split` as:

```
String[] spBifrost = getItemQuantity(<pass_key_here>).split(";");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I understand everything except the split part. I know why I have to use split, but where in the code do I place it and what do I type instead of "string_default_value"?

Comment: @Matthew : you just need to use `getItemQuantity(<pass_key_here>).split(";");` instead of `string_default_value`

Comment: But where do I have to place this? I tried getting it like getItemQuantity("cb4").split(";"); and it didn't work (it would only allow me to do that if I changed the method to return String[]

Comment: @Matthew : you will need to place `String[] spBifrost = getItemQuantity("cb4").split(";");' where u are calling getItemQuantity method for getting SharedPreferences value

Comment: Check my original post edit please, this is how I am now calling getItemQuantity but split still isn't working, checkbox1 is still getting all the 24 items

Comment: @Matthew : ok split method not working so try to use `,` instead of `;` for separating String items or any other separator

Comment: Tried using some other seperators and all I get is 'item1,item2,item3...' or 'item1;item2;item3...' but what I'm trying ot get it only item1 for checkbox1, item2 for checkbox2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy, you just can not put an array to Shared Prefs. Also `itemQuantitySP.getString(key, spBifrost.toString());` must return String, not a Array of Strings. So if you need to return some default value from that array just do like this :

```
itemQuantitySP.getString(key, spBifrost[itemPositionThatYouWantToUseAsDefault]);
```

Comment: But what would then be the easiest way to set a default value for every single checkbox? I have 24 of them, making 24 different sharedpreferences would be a waste, would it? Or is there no other way? For example, if I use itemQuantity.getString(key, spBifrost[1]); I'm pretty sure that's only usable on checkbox1 then because it will always return the same default value, but I want 24 different default values.